# WordPress admin and front end not opening

Tags: php, wordpress

My site is http://www.empoweryourfamily.org/wordpress/

I was working on a plugin and wrote the following code in `functions.php`

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'table' );
function table() {
    wp_register_script('table1', plugins_url() . '/Webinar_Reg/table.js', false, null, true);
    if(is_admin()){
         wp_enqueue_script('table1'); 
    } 
}
```

But, the moment I clicked on update everything went blank and now neither the frontend nor the backend is opening.

Comment: change `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` to `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in wp-config.php file to see error reporting....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely have a syntax error in functions.php or the function `table()` is already defined.

Try rolling back the changes you just applied.
Otherwise try looking in the server log for a specific error.

Comment: On a side note: using `table` as function name in the global namespace is asking for a kick in the balls. At least use `myplugin_table` or a [anonymous function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) instead of named function.

Answer (score 0):

Using `table` as a function name is bad practice. You should name a function in such a way that it will be completely unique. Use something like `mypluginname_table` or `mytheme_table` where mypluginname is the name of your plugin and mytheme the name of your theme. And remember, function names needs to be unique, no two functions can have the same name, except if one is wrapped in a `if(!function_exists()) {}` conditional statement

Answer (score 0):

I just replaced the modified functions.php file with the old(backup file) file and it is opening properly now. Thanks for your answers.